# How was Dutch’s final booby trap intended to function?

Tags: plot-explanation, predator

In [*Predator* (1987)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093773/), prior to the final battle Dutch fashions a booby trap involving a pulley system that uses a log and what look like daggers.

At the end of the final battle Dutch finds himself in the perfect position to execution that final booby trap. However the Predator discovers the trap and decides not to enter.

Apparently Dutch uses ‘the counterweight’ (ie the log) to kill the Predator.

Can someone explain the original booby trap? What would have happened to the Predator if it walked into the the area?

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, Dutch was hoping the Predator would walk through a certain path and he would release the counterweight, which would swing the spike-plated log through said path and impale the Predator.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m not an engineer but the spikes were on the roof of the cave area. Also the counterweight fell straight down. So I’m not certain on the swinging. 

Could it have been that there was a lattice on the floor that releasing the counterweight causes a trapping Of the lattice and slamming it on to the spiked roof?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're right. It seems there were several vines across the bottom of that tight ravine. The idea seems to be Predator walks through, hits the stick, the counterweight drops, pulling the vines up and impaling the Predator on the spikes above him.